# Understanding backpropagation

Tags: derivatives, neural-networks

I was studying some neural networks back propagation from

http://jeremykun.com/2012/12/09/neural-networks-and-backpropagation/

I did not catch how did he achieve this part.

Could someone explain to me?

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Which part? Or all of it?

Comment: This portion which I took a picture of.

Answer (score 2):

The goal is to change the weights so as to bring the loss function $E(\omega)$ to a global mininum; mathematically this can be described by the following update rule

$$\omega\rightarrow -\omega + \eta\nabla E(\omega)$$

with the gradient given by

$$\nabla E(\omega) = \left ( \frac{\partial E}{\partial \omega_1}, \frac{\partial E}{\partial \omega_2} , ..., \frac{\partial E}{\partial \omega_n}  \right )$$

As stated by the author in the link, the loss function is given by

$$E(\omega) = \frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{k=0}^n (y_i-f(x_j))^2$$

so the gradient of this is

$$\frac{\partial }{\partial \omega_i} E(\omega) = \frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{k=0}^n \frac{\partial }{\partial \omega_i}(y_i-f(x_j))^2 = \frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{k=0}^n \frac{\partial }{\partial \omega_i}(y_i^2-2y_i f(x_j) + f(x_j)^2)$$

$$... = \frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{k=0}^n (-2y_i \frac{\partial }{\partial \omega_i}f(x_j) + \frac{\partial }{\partial \omega_i} f(x_j)^2) = - \sum\limits_{k=0}^n (y_i - f(x_j)) \frac{\partial }{\partial \omega_i} f(x_j)$$

The final derivative turns into

$$ \frac{\partial }{\partial \omega_i} f(x_j) = \sum\limits_{l=0}^n \frac{\partial \omega_l}{\partial \omega_i}  x_j = \sum\limits_{l=0}^n \delta_{li}  x_{j,l} = x_{j,i}$$

as the i-th term is the only who survives the partial derivative.

Now it's just a matter of putting all these components back into the first equation to get the final result.

Hope it helps!

Comment: In your example, what does η represent?

Comment: It's the learning rate i.e. for each iteration, how big is the change you perform on the weights. If the value is too small you'll take a long time to converge, if it's too big you might miss some important minima and converge to non-optimal ones so there's a balance to find with this parameter.

Comment: I thought you expressed that with the alpha symbol, I guess you can choose whatever you like? Do you happen to know what the most commenly used symbol is for the learning rate? I have mostly seen the alpha symbol used to denote the learning rate.

Comment: Yes, usually people use alpha but it can be any symbol you choose.